# Python- Geometric Primitives for GIS and Producing a Polygon

Tags: python, gis, polygon, computational-geometry, primitive

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self, xVal, yVal):
    self.xCoord = xVal
    self.yCoord = yVal
    def distanceTo(self, anotherPoint):
       a = self.xCoord - anotherPoint.xCoord
       b = self.yCoord - anotherPoint.yCoord
       return math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))

class Line:
   def __init__(self, verticesList = []):
       self.vertices = verticesList
```

I am designing a mock Geographic Information System from scratch using the description below for my vector data. I am extremely out of my realm of expertise (hence the very little code I've been able to write for this) and would love how to go about doing this using all the information provided.

**Objects of type point need to have the following attributes and methods:**

xCoord | The location of the point on the x-axis.

yCoord | The location of the point on the y-axis.

distanceTo(anotherPoint) | A method accepting another point object and returning the distance from this point to that point, using the Pythagorean Theorem.

**init**(xVal, yVal) | Initialization expects two float objects, and uses them to set this xCoord and this yCoord.

**Objects of type line need to have these attributes and methods:**

vertices | A list containing a sequence of point objects defining the vertices along the line.

calculateLength() | A method that returns the length of this line object, by calculating the sum of the distances between successive vertices in the line.

**init**(verticesList) | Initialization expects a list, expected to be of point objects, and sets this vertices attribute with it.

**Objects of type polygon need to have these attributes and methods:**

ring | A line object defining the perimeter of the polygon.

getBoundingBox() | A method that returns a 4-tuple representing the bounding coordinates of this polygon, of format (minX, minY, maxX, maxY).

**init**(aLine) | Initialization expects a line object, setting this ring attribute with it.

**Vertex positions: (0.0, 0.0) (1.0, 1.0) (3.0, 1.5) (3.9, 0.25) (2.0, -0.7) (0.0, 0.0)**

I've also been tasked to create a line object, 6 vertices long and closed using the vertex positions, producing a polygon.

Comment: please fix the indentation of the code provided - its currenty incorrect

Comment: add the needed other methods as mocks as well - start from there. To get a bounding box you need the highest and lowest x and y coords of all points included in the poligon - you can get that using max and min and looping over the pointsinisde the polygone. You already got the distance method between 2 points - to get a length of a line you simply add the distances between any point_1 to point_2 + point_2 to point_3 + ... points in order - where is your exact problem? Currently this looks like a homework or assessment dump.

Comment: (I more or less missed your question for words missing from `would love how to go about` - *to know*? *to get hints/suggestions/advice*?)

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework, doesn't it ?